# Python: error loading JSON object

Tags: python, json, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to load the following JSON string in python:

```
{
"Motivo_da_Venda_Perdida":"",
"Data_Visita":"2015-03-17 08:09:55",
"Cliente":{
"Distribuidor1_Modelo":"",
"RG":"",
"Distribuidor1_Marca":"Selecione",
"PlataformaMilho1_Quantidade":"",
"Telefone_Fazenda":"",
"Pulverizador1_Quantidade":"",
"Endereco_Fazenda":"",
"Nome_Fazenda":"",
"Area_Total_Fazenda":"",
"PlataformaMilho1_Marca":"Selecione",
"Trator1_Modelo":"",
"Tipo_Cultura3":"Selecione",
"Tipo_Cultura4":"Selecione",
"Cultura2_Hectares":"",
"Colheitadeira1_Quantidade":"",
"Tipo_Cultura1":"Soja",
"Tipo_Cultura2":"Selecione",
"Plantadeira1_Marca":"Stara",
"Autopropelido1_Modelo":"",
"Email_Fazenda":"",
"Autopropelido1_Marca":"Stara",
"Distribuidor1_Quantidade":"",
"PlataformaMilho1_Modelo":"",
"Trator1_Marca":"Jonh deere",
"Email":"",
"CPF":"46621644000",
"Endereco_Rua":"PAQUINHAS, S/N",
"Caixa_Postal_Fazenda":"",
"Cidade_Fazenda":"",
"Plantadeira1_Quantidade":"",
"Colheitadeira1_Marca":"New holland",
"Data_Nascimento":"2015-02-20",
"Cultura4_Hectares":"",
"Nome_Cliente":"MILTON CASTIONE",
"Cep_Fazenda":"",
"Telefone":"5491290687",
"Cultura3_Hectares":"",
"Trator1_Quantidade":"",
"Cultura1_Hectares":"",
"Autopropelido1_Quantidade":"",
"Pulverizador1_Modelo":"",
"Caixa_Postal":"",
"Estado":"RS",
"Endereco_Numero":"",
"Cidade":"COLORADO",
"Colheitadeira1_Modelo":"",
"Pulverizador1_Marca":"Selecione",
"CEP":"99460000",
"Inscricao_Estadual":"0",
"Plantadeira1_Modelo":"",
"Estado_Fazenda":"RS",
"Bairro":""
},
"Quilometragem":"00",
"Modelo_Pretendido":"Selecione",
"Quantidade_Prevista_Aquisicao":"",
"Id_Revenda":"1",
"Contato":"05491290687",
"Pendencia_Para_Proxima_Visita":"",
"Data_Proxima_Visita":"2015-04-17 08:09:55",
"Valor_de_Venda":"",
"Maquina_Usada":"0",
"Id_Vendedor":"2",
"Propensao_Compra":"Propensao_Compra_Frio",
"Comentarios":"despertar compra",
"Sistema_Compra":"Sistema_Compra_Finame",
"Outro_Produto":"",
"Data_Prevista_Aquisicao":"2015-04-17 08:09:55",
"Objetivo_Visita":"Despertar_Interesse",
"Tipo_Contato":"Telefonico"}
```

however I get the following error when I try to load it

```
File "python_file.py", line 107, in busca_proxima_mensagem
  Visita = json.loads(corpo)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
  return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
  raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 2 - line 6 column 84 (char 1 - 1020)
```

but this JSON seems to be valid according to this site: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ What am I doing wrong? Why can't I load this string as a JSON object?

I'm trying to load the string from AWS SQS like this:

```
import json
...
result = fila.get_messages(1, 30, 'SentTimestamp')
for message in result:
    corpo = message.get_body()
    Visita = json.loads(corpo)
```

---

OK, so I figured out what is causing me problems: There is a slash as a value of a key

```
"Endereco_Rua":"PAQUINHAS, S/N",
```

However I'm telling python to filter that out (code below), but it's not working. How can I remove that? Can do it on the origin that created the data, as I don't have access to the interface the user uses to fill in.

```
result = fila.get_messages(1, 30, 'SentTimestamp')
for message in result:
    corpo = message.get_body()
    corpo = corpo.replace("/", "") #Filtering slashes
    Visita = json.loads(corpo)
```

Comment: Where is your code that tries to load the JSON?

Comment: i have no problem. please show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution! Beside the slash caracter, sometimes this error also happened with no visible cause. Ended up solving this by adding the following lines in my python code:

1) At the start of my code, along with other python imports

```
from boto.sqs.message import RawMessage
```

2) Changing my SQS queue to use/fetch raw data:

```
fila = sqs_conn.get_queue(constantes.fila_SQS)
fila.set_message_class(RawMessage)
```

Hope this helps anyone who is having the same issue.